# Show image based on date VB Script

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am extremely new to VB Script, and any help is extremely appreciated.

I currently have 4 images that need to be displayed based on the date. I have named each image as 1,2,3 and 4. I am using the date function to display this but I am getting a 500 error message. If there is a better way to accomplish this with VBScript please let me know. The images are in a folder specified in the path for the src inside the div and the extension of the images is PNG.

```
   <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%> 

<%
Dim CurDate

'CurDate = Month(DATE)
'CurDate =("2018-11-01")
 CurDate =(DATE)    

response.write(CurDate) 

If CurDate = "2018-10-30" THEN
    CurDate = 1
If CurDate = "2018-11-01" THEN
    CurDate = 2

If CurDate = "2018-11-02" THEN
    CurDate = 3

Else CureDate = 4

End If

%>  

     HTML Below


  <div style="padding-left:10px;text-align:center;">
    <img alt="Image- Displaying" border="0" src="http://Path/Default/Pane/imgFolder/<%=CurDate%>.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Lankymart thank you for the comment but I am a little unsure. No, it's not a duplicate question. But for sure will use that post as a reference. Thank you a million.

Comment: It definitely is, the problem is you are trying to compare dates but you are using the string representation of a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is with your if/else/then.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%> 

<%
Dim CurDate

'CurDate = Month(DATE)
'CurDate =("2018-11-01")
 CurDate =(DATE)    

response.write(CurDate) 

If CurDate = "2018-10-30" THEN
    CurDate = 1
elseIf CurDate = "2018-11-01" THEN
    CurDate = 2
elseIf CurDate = "2018-11-02" THEN
    CurDate = 3
Else
    CurDate = 4
End If
%>  

     HTML Below


<div style="padding-left:10px;text-align:center;">
  <img alt="Image- Displaying" border="0" src="http://Path/Default/Pane/imgFolder/<%=CurDate%>.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this was the main issue as you mentioned if/else/then statement .I am able to view the date and image now.  At least I am able to pick it up from here. It is still not working to its fullest because everything gets defaulted to the Else statement. But I will pick it up from here. Thank you Very Much.

Comment: Do if curdate = cdate("2018-10-30"), to compare date with date, instead comparing date with string.
And, can you mark my answer a accepted?

Comment: No as you pointed out in the comments, the problem is comparing a date to a string which has already been pointed out as a duplicate question.

Comment: The main issue (error 500) was not due to a date comparison.  It was a syntax error.

Comment: Just reading the code I was able to know what was the error, even if the question was not enough detailled.  There were many errors.  A syntax error was more important since the script didn't work at all.